# MongoDB Query using nested groups

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

With this given data.

```javascript
{ "_id" : 0, "a" : 0, "b" : 0, "c" : 21 }
{ "_id" : 1, "a" : 0, "b" : 0, "c" : 54 }
{ "_id" : 2, "a" : 0, "b" : 1, "c" : 52 }
{ "_id" : 3, "a" : 0, "b" : 1, "c" : 17 }
{ "_id" : 4, "a" : 1, "b" : 0, "c" : 22 }
{ "_id" : 5, "a" : 1, "b" : 0, "c" : 5 }
{ "_id" : 6, "a" : 1, "b" : 1, "c" : 87 }
{ "_id" : 7, "a" : 1, "b" : 1, "c" : 97 }
```

The query is this

```javascript
db.fun.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: { a: "$a", b: "$b" },
        c: { $max: "$c" }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$_id.a",
        c: { $min: "$c" }
    }
}])
```

The correct answer is

```
54 and 22
```

How come is it like that? I was expecting to be `97 and 21`

Why have I thought of 97 as max and 21 as min? becaus all of the documents that has a similar values(namely a and b) 
c is the highest and the lowest is 21

can someone eloborate this to me? and how $group really work?

Comment: the correct answer is `52 and 22`, not `54 and 22`.

Answer (score 1):

First `$group` gives you result of grouping by `a` and `b` and selecting max value of `c`. So, for example, it gets `a=0` and `b=0` combinations:

```
{ "_id" : 0, "a" : 0, "b" : 0, "c" : 21 }
{ "_id" : 1, "a" : 0, "b" : 0, "c" : 54 }
```

and for this it will group them and select max of `21` or `54`, which is `54`. So you get this result for all groups:

```
    {
        "_id" : {
            "a" : 1,
            "b" : 1
        },
        "c" : 97
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
            "a" : 1,
            "b" : 0
        },
        "c" : 22
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
            "a" : 0,
            "b" : 1
        },
        "c" : 52
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
            "a" : 0,
            "b" : 0
        },
        "c" : 54
    }
```

This is what your second `$group` will get to work with. And at this time it groups by `a` and selects min of `c`. So you can see that for `a=1` min of `c` (from `22` and `97`) will be `22` and for `a=0` min `c` (from `52` and `54`) will be `52`.

So it is how you get `22` and `52`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is really easy to look at from a relational (SQL) perspective, because `$group` in your scenario is very similar to SQL's `GROUP BY`.

So, assuming your data was in a table called `MongoData` with columns `A`, `B` and `C`, this is how the select equivalent to your aggregation would look like:

```sql
select A, min(C) MinC
from (
    select A, max(C)
    from MongoData
    group by A, B
  ) X (A, C)
group by A;
```

The results after running step 1 of the aggregation (or the inner Select) are:

```
A   B   MaxC
------------
0   0   54
1   0   22
0   1   52
1   1   97
```

Step2 reduces this data by grouping only by `A` to:

```
A   MinC
--------
0   52
1   22
```

Take a look at this SQLFiddle to see how the data looks after each of the two steps: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d4f5/10